# How to structure firebase messaging database

Tags: android, firebase, messaging

Good day, I'm currently working on a Real-Time-Messaging App just like WhatsApp, and I'm using Firebase. I've read several tutorials on stack overflow but I'm always lost in the middle.
I want a messaging between two diffrent user privately

Question:
How to structure my firebase database for messaging between two different user privately.?

Answer (score 0):

I worked on a similar project a few months ago. You want 1 field for the sender, one field for the receiver, one for the actual text content, and maybe a few more if you want to add 'read message' or reactions to texts.